# Multiple fields types for nested form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

My app has got location, each location got many IPs. Using railscasts relevant episode (http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) I have built a `location` form which includes the `ip`s list and an option to add new ones. Each `ip` has its `text_field` generated by the form.

Thing is, I want the existing `ip`s to appear as `label`s rather than editable text boxes, something like this:

- existing (read only)
- existing (read only)
- existing (read only)

*new link*

and upon clicking the link, an editable textbox is appended. Any ideas?

---

**Models**:

*location.rb*:

```
class Ip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :location
  validates_uniqueness_of :address
  [...]
end
```

*ip.rb*:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ips
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ips
  [...]
end
```

**Controller**:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  [...]
  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:name, ips_attributes: [:id, :address])
  end
end
```

**Helper**:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  [...]  
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_obj = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_obj, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to name, "#", onclick: "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"
  end
end
```

**Views**:

*/locations/_form.html.erb*:

```
<header>
  <script>
    function add_fields(link, association, content) {
      var new_id = new Date().getTime();
      var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
      $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
    }
  </script>
</header>
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
  [...]
  <%= f.label :ips, t('location.ips') %>
  <%= f.fields_for :ips do |builder| %>
    <%= redner "ip_fields", f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to_add_fields t('location.add_ip'), f, :ips %>
  </p>
  [...]
<% end %>
```

*_ip_fields.html.erb*:

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
</p>
```

The relevant HTML:

```
  <label for="location_ips">Addresses</label>

    <p class="fields">
    <input type="text" value="1.2.3.5" name="location[ips_attributes][0][address]" id="location_ips_attributes_0_address" />
</p>

<input type="hidden" value="19" name="location[ips_attributes][0][id]" id="location_ips_attributes_0_id" />
    <p class="fields">
    <input type="text" value="2.3.4.5" name="location[ips_attributes][1][address]" id="location_ips_attributes_1_address" />
</p>

<input type="hidden" value="20" name="location[ips_attributes][1][id]" id="location_ips_attributes_1_id" />
    <p class="fields">
    <input type="text" value="3.4.5.6" name="location[ips_attributes][2][address]" id="location_ips_attributes_2_address" />
</p>

<input type="hidden" value="21" name="location[ips_attributes][2][id]" id="location_ips_attributes_2_id" />
    <p class="fields">
    <input type="text" value="9.9.9.9" name="location[ips_attributes][3][address]" id="location_ips_attributes_3_address" />
</p>

<input type="hidden" value="22" name="location[ips_attributes][3][id]" id="location_ips_attributes_3_id" />
  <p>
    <a onclick="add_fields(this, &quot;ips&quot;, &quot;&lt;p class=\&quot;fields\&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;input type=\&quot;text\&quot; name=\&quot;location[ips_attributes][new_ips][address]\&quot; id=\&quot;location_ips_attributes_new_ips_address\&quot; /&gt;\n&lt;\/p&gt;\n&quot;)" href="#">add new IP address</a>
    </p>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant html snippet from the browser.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin done

Comment: Someting strange.  How do you get 0, 1, 2 and 3 for `new_ips` from `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: What I would do is generate a `<span>...</` followed by an `<input type="hidden"  ...>` for the read only stuff and a `<input type="text"  ...>` for the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't pretty (logic in the view isn't recommended) but it provides the solution I wanted: an extra parameter in the helper method to signal for a non-labelled field, then refactoring the partial conditional on the existence of this variable

helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  [...]  
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_obj = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_obj, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder, labelled: false)
    end
    link_to name, "#", onclick: "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"
  end
end
```

*_ip_fields.html.erb*:

```
<p class="fields">
  <% if (defined? labelled) %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.label :address, f.object.address %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```